# Rails 3: Problem with a route to new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a problem with rails 3 routes.

I want add a new action called "gestion_etudiant" with a new view "gestion_etudiant.html.erb".

I have on my index page a link like this

```
<%= link_to "Administration", {:controller => "users", :action => "gestion_etudiant"} %>
```

I also try this:

```
<%= link_to "Administration", "/users/gestion_etudiant" %>
```

In my controller:

```
def gestion_etudiant
  @users = User.find(:all)
end
```

but when I clic on the link, I always have this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with ID=gestion_etudiant
```

I have this in my routes file:

```
resources :users
```

And I've also try to add:

```
match "users/gestion_etudiant", :to => "users#gestion_etudiant"
```

and

```
resources :users, :only => [:gestion_etudiant]
```

But I can not access my page "gestion_etudiant.html.erb". Can anybody suggest why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# router:

resources :users do
  get :gestion_etudiant, :on => :collection
end

# view:

link_to "Administration", gestion_etudiant_users_path

# Controller

def gestion_etudiant
  @users = User.all # Don't use find with :all as it will be deprecated in rails 3.1
end
```

Comment: Thx for your response. The error has disappeared :). but now when I click on the link I am redirected to the index (the page just refreshes). I don't why. When I put the cursor on the link I have "http://localhost:3000/users/gestion_etudiant but it won't works...

Answer (score 1):

In your routes, try:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'gestion_etudiant'
  end
end
```

You can check the routes you have in your application by running `rake routes`